# Writing inside of xml file by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, document

i have a simple javascript code im using an api for taking data . and im transforming it to xml languege and printing in html text area . But i need to take this data ,transform to xml languege and write this data to inside of xml file. Does anyone done this before ?

i tried so much ways to open xml file and edit it but u just can read it. I cant edit xml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't let you write data and then save it on the server. You need a backend that manage this type of thing.

You can generate an .xml file and make the user download it

[xmlwrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-writer) let you create an XML file which can be saved then

```
var XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');
xw = new XMLWriter;
xw.startDocument();
xw.startElement('root');
xw.writeAttribute('foo', 'value');
xw.text('Some content');
xw.endDocument();

var file = new Blob([xw.toString()], {type: 'text/plain'});
save_button.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
save_button.download = 'file.xml';
```

Where `save_button` id should be associated to an `<a>` tag such as `<a href="" id="save_button">Download XML</a>`

Comment: i did that but still cant add anything to xml file

Comment: @emrekoc have you installed the module first?

Comment: yes i installed it

Comment: @emrekoc to add to the XLM content you need to use the `writeAttribute` and `text`

Comment: I used the same code as yours  and on the html side, I used this     <a download="file.xml" href="" id="save_button">Download XML</a>

Comment: i guess require xml-writer part doesnt working in html browser js side

Comment: `download="file.xml"` inside the `a` tag is not necessary. Also, it may be because you have no Node.js installed, so basically no backend runtime

Comment: i have node.js but I came across this while searching the internet for require problem

Comment: "This is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript."